# How to get the cell reference of the second smallest value from a range of data

Tags: excel

I need to get the cell reference (specifically I only need the column number) of the second smallest value from a range of data.Complicated by the fact that the values in the range can be the same.
eg.

```
A B C D E    
1 5 2 1 8
```

Should return D as my column with the second smallest value.

The current part of my code is as below:

=SMALL('Sheet1'!C38:X38,2),'Sheet1'!C38:X38,0)

However this leaves me with the problem that if the second smallest value is the same as the first only the first will be matched and returned.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: So it is the second smallest and if a tie it should be the one to the right?  Also why do you want the column?  is it the end result or are you going to use the result in another formula, because using INDEX will skip that need.

Comment: If it's a tie then it should just move on to the next one along in the array (like the SMALL function does). And I need the reference not the value because I use the column number to find another cell.

Comment: That is what I asked.  You want it to go from left to right.  Some cultures would read it right to left.

Answer (score 2):

Use Aggregate to return the column number which you then would supply to an INDEX formula to return the other value:

```
=INDEX($A$3:$E$3,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$1:$E$1)/($A$1:$E$1=SMALL($A$1:$E$1,2)),MIN(2,COUNTIF($A$1:$E$1,SMALL($A$1:$E$1,2)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thankyou! Trying it out now :)

Edit: It works beautifully! Thankyou so much, this has really helped me out a lot :)